# Trying to extract two different sets of data in one query

Tags: mysql

I have three tables that will be involved in one query. This is what the query is trying to do:

A player creates a trade offer. The trade offers table structure is as such:

```
id              int(11)
sender          int(11)
receiver        int(11)
offer           text
request         text
active          tinyint(1)
slot_upgrade    int(11)
```

When the player creats a trade offer, the ID of their **city** from which they sent the trade is stored in the `sender` field, and the ID of the target **city** that they are sending the trade to is stored in the `receiver` field.

Now when a player logs in, I want to extract all active trades.

I had something like this:

```
SELECT ct.id, ct.offer, ct.request, cities.name, cities.userid, cities.x, cities.y,users.username
    FROM cities_trades AS ct
        LEFT JOIN cities ON ct.sender = cities.id
        LEFT JOIN users ON cities.id = users.id
    WHERE ct.active = 1 AND (ct.sender IN (1,2) OR ct.receiver IN (1,2))
```

This query would find all active *(active meaning that the `active tinyint(1)` field is set to 1)* trades in the `cities_trades` table.

It would also extract the sender's `userid` by doing a `LEFT JOIN` on the `cities` table using the `sender` field in the `cities_trades` table that correlates to the city id in the `cities` table.

By doing this, I can extract any information from the `cities` table and `users` table for the trade creator, or in this case, the **sender**.

But if I also want to pull all the same information about the `receiver`, not just `sender` (I want info on them both), how could I do this?

The only other solution I can think of is to simplify the query by add two new fields to the `cities_trades` table to store their relative player ID's, such as, instead of solely their city ids.

`sender_player_id`
`receiver_player_id`

I hope this question makes sense. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may actually perform two joins against the `cities` table, one for each side of the trading transaction. Use a different alias for each as `cities_sender` and `cities_receiver` (or similar). You may then list them all in the `SELECT`.

```
SELECT 
  ct.id,
  ct.offer, 
  ct.request,
  -- Specify all sender columns with an alias
  cities_sender.name AS sender_name,
  cities_sender.userid AS sender_userid,
  cities_sender.x AS sender_x,
  cities_sender.y AS sender_y,
  -- Then specify all receiver columns with a different alias
  cities_receiver.name AS receiver_name,
  cities_receiver.userid AS receiver_userid,
  cities_receiver.x AS receiver_x,
  cities_receiver.y AS receiver_y,
  -- Also for usernames on both sides of the relationship
  users_sender.username AS sender_username,
  users_receiver.username AS receiver_username
FROM
  cities_trades AS ct
  -- Join once for the sender side
  LEFT JOIN cities AS cities_sender ON ct.sender = cities_sender.id
  -- Join again for the receiver side
  LEFT JOIN cities AS cities_receiver ON ct.receiver = cities_receiver.id
  -- Likewise, for users
  LEFT JOIN users users_sender ON cities_sender.id = users_sender.id
  LEFT JOIN users users_receiver ON cities_receiver.id = users_receiver.id
WHERE
   ct.active = 1
   AND (ct.sender IN (1,2) OR ct.receiver IN (1,2))
```

Edit: Added both sender/receiver joins for the username as well...

Comment: Awesome! I didn't think joining the same table twice was possible. Really appreciate the speedy and quality response.

Comment: @josh Glad to help, good luck. You may join the same table any number of times as long as you differentiate with aliases.